# Items Are Not Being Added In List<Object> When Getting Json In AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I've a RecyclerView, Async Task, Json File .

What i want : 
Get the Json and add an item for every loop .

My problem : 
I'm getting the json, and looping, But the "List.add(Item)" isn't adding any line, So the recycler is empty .

Code :

```
Adapter RcAdapter;
public static List<CatItem> Items;
String DATA_URL;
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_recycler,
            container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    DATA_URL = this.getArguments().getString(MainActivity.DATA);
    initListViews();
    return LinLayout;
}

    private void initListViews() {
    List<CatItem> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    LinearLayoutManager gridLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    RecyclerView RcView = (RecyclerView) LinLayout.findViewById(R.id.cat_rv);

    RcView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RcView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);
    RcAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);

    RcView.setAdapter(RcAdapter);
}

    private List<CatItem> getAllItemList() {

    Items = new ArrayList<>();

    new GetDevices().execute(DATA_URL);

    return Items;
}

class GetDevices extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Devices, Please Wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();

        if(result == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed To Fetch Data, Please Refresh",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject MainJSON = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray DevicesArrays = MainJSON.getJSONArray("roms_center");

                for (int i = 0; i < DevicesArrays.length() ; i++){
                    CatItem Item = new CatItem();
                    JSONObject first = DevicesArrays.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.LogInfo("I'm In Position " + i);

                    Item.setDevice_Name(first.getString("device_name"));
                    Item.setTotal_Downloads(first.getInt("roms_count"));
                    Item.setDevice_ID(first.getInt("device_id"));

                    Items.add(Item);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What's the problem ?

Also, In my holder i've implemented OnClick, and i want to get something from the pressed position, I'm using the following way :

```
Main.Items.get(getLayoutPosition()).getDevice_ID()
```

As you can see, I'm getting the static List, Any better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've added an item to your list you have to tell your adapter about it. So you could do it in two ways:

```
RcAdapter.notifyItemInserted(Items.size() - 1);
or
RcAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

Comment: @Ravjit Singh is also right. So just don't return Items, use one of the methods I showed you and you should be fine if I'm not missing something. Also change `List<CatItem> rowListItem = getAllItemList();`to `List<CatItem> rowListItem;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, That what i needed, Also please point me out for the second question .

Answer (score 2):

The program flow between these two lines is not what you think it is.

```
new GetDevices().execute(DATA_URL);
return Items;
```

GetDevices is an AsyncTask, which means it will run asynchronously. 
The return statement in the next line will not wait for the async task to finish, and it returns null because async task takes time to finish.